# Biological Cell shape detection with Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a problem with shape detection on Matlab. I got two types of circular cell shapes but one is erythrocyte that has little difference to another cell that is leukocyte and is also circular. How could I distinguish them from each other with image processing?

Maybe will parent-child relationship be useful to detect circle in erythrocyte? Or other techniques?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed a few example images. What kind of microscopy is used to acquire those images? Can you tell by eye what a discriminating feature is? Can you stain with DAPI?

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 types of cell detection/segmentation: pixel-based, region-based, edge-based and contour-based segmentation. You may use one or several combinations of them for your task. But counting only on the shape may be insufficient.

The main difference between erythrocyte and leukocyte is the existence of nucleus. To my knowledge, the nucleus staining is often applied to microscopy. If that is the case,

(i) the ratio between green and blue channel intensities of each pixel can be used as discriminating feature to separate the nucleus pixels from other foreground pixels;

(ii) After that, it is possible to extract the leukocyte plasma based on the hue-value similarity between the pixel from that region and the nucleus region;

(iii) Contour-based methods such as active-contour methods (snakes) and level-set approaches can be used to refine the boundaries of white blood cells;

(iv) What left to you after (i)-(iii) are probably the erythrocytes. If your task also includes the segmentation of erythrocytes, you may threshold them easily (or search the studies for more accurate segmentation algorithms).

I would recommend [T.Bergen et al, Segmentation of leukocytes and erythrocytes in blood smear images](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19163356). My description above was included and detailed in this paper, and they applied more sophisticated strategies to improve the boundary accuracy. You may try to follow their steps and reproduce the similar result if your ultimate goal is also segmentation. Yet only detection without extraction might be much easier.